# Fail to insert in hive using jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, hive, insert, denodo

I try to insert into hive using jdbc driver 'hive-jdbc-2.1.1-cdh6.3.0-standalone.jar' (through denodo tool) but it always fails to insert and error appears that method not supported .. I retrieve data successfully but fail to insert...any help please?

```
  ERROR 2020-04-27T11:56:06.642 com.denodo.scheduler.core.exporter.jdbc.JDBCExporter [] - Connection error in JDBCExporter.  
com.denodo.scheduler.core.dataSource.connection.ServerConnectionException: Method not supported
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.dataSource.connection.JDBCConnection.commit(Unknown Source) ~[denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.exporter.jdbc.JDBCExporter.export(Unknown Source) [denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.job.ExportationJob.exportDocuments(Unknown Source) [denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.job.ExportationJob.doProcess(Unknown Source) [denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.job.AbstractDatabaseExtractionJob.processDocuments(Unknown Source) [denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.job.AbstractDatabaseExtractionJob.extractDocuments(Unknown Source) [denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.job.AbstractDatabaseExtractionJob.extractDocuments(Unknown Source) [denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.job.task.QueryJob.call(Unknown Source) [denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at com.denodo.scheduler.core.job.task.QueryJob.call(Unknown Source) [denodo-scheduler-core.jar:7.0.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_162]
```

Comment: Not an expert on Denodo, but I think what error tells you is that `commit()` is not supported by the Hive JDBC driver. You should figure out how to stop Denodo from issuing commits, maybe disable transaction support?

Comment: Thanks I solved it . Problem was  hive jdbc used not support insertion method so I changed the jdbc driver

Comment: Might be worth posting it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it . Problem was hive jdbc used not support insertion method so I changed the jdbc driver and use latest hive jdbc cloudera